# Pulling new information from JSON on Button click using Volley / RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I have an android app that currently pulls information from an SQL database using PHP to convert it into a JSON string

my code successfully pulls up the information on application start up and populates the RecyclerView as expected with my database contents.

My idea is to have 2 buttons that will switch between 2 sets of information in the same RecyclerView.

**My Problem**

So I have created a button and on Button Click I would like it to change the URL that the JSON output is located **(example.com/api.php)** and use a new URL with a separate JSON output **(example.com/api2.php)**

Essentially switching the source of the data for the RecyclerView and then I need to reload the new results inside the running app.

**My Question**

How is it possible to change the value of

```
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://example.com/Api.php";
```

***TO***

```
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://example.com/Api2.php";
```

***THEN***

Somehow refresh my RecyclerView with the new information.

***MY ATTEMPT***

```
        simpleButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        simpleButton1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        menuButton.setText("Menu");
        URL_PRODUCTS = "http://example.com/Api.php"
#### I HAVE NO IDEA HOW TO REFRESH THE RECYCLERVIEW#######
```

**SOME OF MY CODE (bits omitted for clarity)**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button simpleButton1;
    boolean menuUp;

    //this is the JSON Data URL
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://example.com/Api.php";

   //a list to store all the products
   List<Product> productList;

   //the recyclerview
   RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

**GET & CONVERT THE DATA**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    simpleButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.simpleButton1);//get id of button 1
    menuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuButton);//get id of button 2


    //getting the recyclerview from xml
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //initializing the productlist
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //this method will fetch and parse json
    //to display it in recyclerview
    loadProducts();
}
```

**MORE**

```
        /*
    * Creating a String Request
    * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
    * The URL is defined in the second parameter
    * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
    * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
    * */
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json array object
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                        //traversing through all the object
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            //getting product object from json array
                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            //adding the product to product list
                            productList.add(new Product(
                                    product.getInt("id"),
                                    product.getString("title"),
                                    product.getString("shortdesc"),
                                    product.getDouble ("rating"),
                                    product.getDouble("price"),
                                    product.getString("image")
                            ));
                        }

                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

MORE

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: In your code, you are using the static **final** (Can't change) field URL_PRODUCTS on the StringRequest instantiation, why don't you try passing the URL as a parameter to the method containing the StringRequest instantiation? That way, you can call the method passing in your required URL. Also, once the data in the productList is changed, you just have to call notifyDatasetChanged() on the adapter. In your case, you are creating a new adapter and passing it to the recyclerview on every response, which will also work.

Comment: I see i was unfamiliar with  the "final" but looking into it i see i have kind of set my URL_PRODUCTS as a constant technically. So that that makes much more sense that you say i should call it when necessary and treat it as a variable, i will change it like that, thanks

Comment: Yes. don't make it final if you want it changed. If you change the url, then you can just _call loadProducts();_ inside the button click (assuming thats the method where the data is being fetched.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define 2 url :

```
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://example.com/Api.php";
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS_2 = "http://example.com/Api2.php";
```

then set up RecyclerView :

```
productList = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
loadProducts(URL_PRODUCTS);//add param for this method then you have to add it to your volley request
```

In your volley's response change 2 line

```
ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Now when click button you will change url

```
simpleButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            productList.clear();
            loadProducts(URL_PRODUCTS_2);
```

Comment: thank you, i have managed to make it work by using the code/info you have provided, cheers